# Screen resolution stuck on 1366x768 59.9hz after repair shop worked on it

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, resolution, windows-installer

I took my MSI Raider GE63 to a repair shop to fix a broken hinge and they gave it back to me with the resolution stuck on 1366x768. They don't know how to fix it and I haven't found a solution myself yet. The screen is supposed to be 1920x1080 @100hz

I have formatted my PC to start fresh (Windows 10), installed my NVIDIA drivers and Intel UHD drivers. I have also tried to set my Nvidia settings to performance so my graphic card should be used all the time.

I updated all drivers and tools listed on [MSI support page](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE63-Raider-RGB-8RF/support) and went through all Windows updates.

Also tried to disable the Intel UHD graphics in device manager. This will change my display driver to Microsoft basic display driver and the resolution stays the same.

Did the store break something? They don't know how to fix this and gave my laptop back after 2 weeks.

Picture of display settings:
[image: picture of display settings]

Comment: Ask them if they fixed the hinge by replacing the lid, and then possibly the wrong display for your machine.

Comment: You need a bootable usb windows 10 environment such as HBCD_PE_x64 - Find this and install to USB - It has very good display driver support and works well with intel UHD. If this still gives you the low res of 1366x768 then the repair shop didn't just change the bracket, they also downgraded your screen....

Comment: @John they did replace the lid, but they should not have replaced the screen. The gave me the old parts back and a screen wasnt one of em.

Comment: @johnnyVegas will be testing this out now.

Comment: some lids are bonded to the LCD display, and sometimes they can be purchased as a complete laptop lid including screen and hinges - especially when second-hand

Comment: On my old MSI laptop - there was a special utility to switch between the nvidia and the built in graphics. I take it this has been installed?

Comment: Yeh that was installed. Still no luck, im going to go back to the store and ask what they actually replaced.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas They ended up replacing the screen at there cost and shipped it to the factory to figure out what went wrong. Doubt ill hear back from them tho

Comment: I hope you also have the laptop back and it's working ok? Very good of the repair shop to do that for you.